# How to use React Router with Electron?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, electron

Using [this boilerplate](https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate) as reference I created an [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) app. It uses webpack to bundle the scripts and express server to host it.

Webpack config is practically same as [this](https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate/blob/master/webpack.config.development.js) and server [this](https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate/blob/master/server.js).

Electron's script loads:

`mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/app/index.html');`

And index.html loads the script hosted by the server:

`<script src="http://localhost:3000/dist/bundle.js"></script>`

I run `electron index.js` to build the app and `node server` to start server which using webpack bundles the scripts.

It works fine, my React component App is mounted. But how I integrate react-router into this?

I implemented it the same way I would in a browser app. I get this error:

`[react-router] Location "/Users/arjun/Documents/Github/electron-app/app/index.html" did not match any routes`

It is taking file path as the route. Going through the boiler plate code did not help. What am I missing?

Comment: Getting the exact same thing. Did you find a solution, @arjun-u – or did you just go for hashHistory instead?

Comment: I used hashHistory.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Another option would be to use **hashHistory** instead. Actually, in your  referenced repo [you can see that they're using **hashHistory**](https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate/blob/b76f537bc784d1102b13675297d54bd28baff9d8/app/store/configureStore.dev.js#L10), how about trying that and posting back?

Comment: HashRouter is deprecated, so I went with Niekert's answer. https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/HashRouter.md

Comment: `HashRouter` is not deprecated in 2019.

Answer (score 167):

#### Had to Replace `BrowserRouter` with `HashRouter`.

```
import {
  HashRouter,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";
```

And then in my `index.js` or the entry file of the Electron app I had something like this:

```
<HashRouter>
  <div>
    <Route path="/" exact     component={ Home } />
    <Route path="/firstPage"  component={ FirstPage } />
    <Route path="/secondPage" component={ SecondPage } />
  </div>
</HashRouter>
```

And then everything just worked.

The reasoning: `BrowserRouter` is meant for request-based environments whereas `HashRouter` is meant for file-based environments.

Read more here:

- https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/HashRouter.md

Comment: Man! you saved my entire week! I tried trillions of combinations and googled it like for ever.. Now, it works like charm! thank you

Comment: @IWIH I had the exact same week so when I found out how to do it I thought I better share it save some other poor soul. Glad it saved you some time and sanity! =-)

Comment: literally* (facepalm)

Comment: In my case this solution didn't helped. I'm still getting a blank page :(

Comment: Thank you so much it's working like a charm❤️ you saved my entire project.

Comment: @JoshuaPinter i created a menu item. 
now i wanted to navigate to another page of my application. 
i am using react Hash Router.  Not sure where do start

Comment: I tried this answer, but still, get a blank page

Comment: @Kingalione Wasn't working for me either until I explicitly set in my webpack config the `devServer.historyApiFallback` property in to `true`. https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhistoryapifallback

Comment: For anyone still getting a blank page, you're likely not including a `#` in `mainWindow.loadURL('file://index.html#/home')`. Check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72563347/15959847) for details.

Comment: seems promising but reactrouter.com/en/6.14.2/router-components/hash-router says "We strongly recommend you do not use HashRouter unless you absolutely have to." which makes me bit uneasy

Comment: @ozgeneral This answer was from 5 years ago. What are they saying to use as an alternative now?

Comment: I asked them here: https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/discussions/10724

it seems like people still use HashRouter although it is deprecated now

Answer (score 27):

I'm using React Router v4 and didn't want to fallback to the `HashRouter`, so I solved it with something amongst the likes of:

```
import { Redirect, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      {window.location.pathname.includes('index.html') && <Redirect to="/" />}
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Comment: Your solution works except reloading electron will lead to a blank page. It's not a problem in "production" but in development I often need to reload. Does it happen to you?

Comment: Worked in terms of loading the app but all imported assets (images/vids) are not loaded!

Answer (score 22):

Best option at the time of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36505404/how-to-use-react-router-with-electron/46307415#46307415) answer is to use the [MemoryRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/MemoryRouter), worked for me :)

Comment: Reloading the page will lose the state though

Answer (score 9):

The (current) [react-router docs say](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/guides/basic-components.md#routers):

> Generally speaking, you should use a <BrowserRouter> if you have a server that responds to requests and a <HashRouter> if you are using a static file server.

An Electron app is basically a static file server.

[MemoryRouter](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/MemoryRouter.md) can also work, so long as all routing originates from within the React part of the app. It only falls down when you want to navigate to a specific page from the Browser process, e.g. you want to pop up a new window and navigate directly to a "General Preferences" page. In that case, you can do this with HashRouter:

```
prefsWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/app/index.html#/general-prefs`);
```

I don't think there is a way to do that with MemoryRouter (from the Browser process).

Answer (score 8):

What about simply using Switch to default to "/" as follows:

```js
<Switch>
  <Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>
  <Route path="/foo" component={Foo}/>
  <Route path="/bar" component={Bar}/>
  <Route render={() => <Redirect to="/"/>}/>
</Switch>
```

This way, "/index.html" will redirect to "/"

Comment: Every refresh leads to an empty site and whole app needs to be refreshed... How did you solve this?

Comment: @maetulj I do have the same problem,

Answer (score 4):

It all depends on what kind of URL you pass to `mainWindow.loadURL`.

#### `file://...`

If you load `index.html` directly through the `file://` protocol, such as

```js
mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + path.join(__dirname, '../index.html#/home'))
```

then you need to use `HashRouter`:

```
<HashRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path='/home' element={<MyHomeScreen/>}>
  </Routes>
</HashRouter>
```

Note that the `#` in `index.html#/home` is **very important**!

Why?

Think about what would happen if you wrote `index.html/home`. Your computer would try to retrieve a `home` file inside an `index.html` directory. The `#` prevents this, and thus we need to use **Hash**Router.

#### `http://localhost:3000`

If you load `index.html` from a server such as `localhost:3000`, then you have two options:

- include the `#`, as in

  ```js
  mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:3000#/home')
  ```

  and use `HashRouter` exactly as above,

**OR**

- don't include the `#`, as in

  ```js
  mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:3000/home')
  ```

  and use `BrowserRouter` like this:

  ```
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/home' element={<MyHomeScreen/>}>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
  ```

Many people prefer to use `BrowserRouter` in this case because it avoids complicating the URL with a `#`.

Answer (score 3):

Agree with Niekert.
But I believe it is better to handle like this before any route management.

```
if ( window.location.pathname.includes('index.html') ) {
    location.pathname = ROUTES.ROOT;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `main` process:

```
mainWindow.loadURL(resolveHtmlPath('index.html'));
```

In your `renderer` process:

```
import { HashRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

//...

<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/search" element={<Search />} />
    <Route
      path="/library"
      element={<Library />}
      />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

The call to `resolveHtmlPath` removed the need for using hashtags for me.  Using a `BrowserRouter` out of the box gave me the warning message in dev tools.

This function is in the [Electron React Boilerplate](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate/blob/main/src/main/util.ts) project that you referenced:

```
import { URL } from 'url';
import path from 'path';

export function resolveHtmlPath(htmlFileName: string) {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    const port = process.env.PORT || 1212;
    const url = new URL(`http://localhost:${port}`);
    url.pathname = htmlFileName;
    return url.href;
  }
  return `file://${path.resolve(__dirname, '../renderer/', htmlFileName)}`;
}
```