# Cannot GET /main_window/page error after manual refresh in React in Electron generated from Electron-forge

Tags: reactjs, webpack, electron, electron-forge

I created an Electron forge project as described in [the forge guide](https://www.electronforge.io/templates/typescript-+-webpack-template) using the "typescript + webpack" template:

```
yarn create electron-app debugging-test --template=typescript-webpack
```

And added React to it, also as described in the guide on a different subpage:

```
yarn add react react-dom
yarn add --dev @types/react @types/react-dom
```

And integrated it like this:

```
{imports section}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/main_window' element={<App />}>
            <Route index element={<HomePage />} />
            <Route path='about' element={<AboutPage />} />
            <Route path='login' element={<LoginPage />} />
            <Route path='*' element={<PageNotFound />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  reactAppDiv);
```

Now when I run the app with `npm start` it works fine but when, for example, login page is displayed and I hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> I get a blank page saying `Cannot GET /main_window/page` with `404` error in the devtools.

[image: 404 error after refresh]

I found a similar issue with "pure" react apps where adding below to webpack's config fixes the issue but in my case adding it to webpack plugin config in `packages.json` doesn't help.

```
"devServer": {
    historyApiFallback: true
},
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TLDR:** Use `HashRouter` instead of `Router`

I had the same issue and solved it based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50404777/8099689). Here are the HashRouter Docs for [react-router-dom-v5](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/HashRouter) and [react-router-dom-v6](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/routers/hash-router).

Using `react-router-dom-v6` within an app based on electron-forge's webpack+typescript template, using `HashRouter` solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

In the forge configuration, add an entryPoint with an empty name.

Something like that:

```js
const config = {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    new WebpackPlugin({
      // ...
      renderer: {
        entryPoints: [
          {
            name: '',
            html: './src/index.html',
            js: './src/renderer.tsx',
            preload: {
              js: './src/preload.ts'
            }
          }
          // ...
        ]
      }
    })
  ]
}
```